# How to register a (Component)SystemEventListener for all UIInputs

Tags: jsf, annotations, faces-config, systemeventlistener

I am trying to have a custom `SystemEventListener` that registers for all instances of type `UIInput` and reacts to their `postValidate`-Events. Based on an example I found on the web I managed to get one running for `HtmlInputText` by registering it in the `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<system-event-listener>
   <source-class>javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText</source-class>
   <system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PostValidateEvent</system-event-class>
   <system-event-listener-class>com.ourcompany.ourproduct.validators.inputPostValidationListener</system-event-listener-class>
 </system-event-listener>
```

I then tried to 1) broaden this to work for UIInputs in general and to 2) use the `@ListenerFor`annotation, but I just can't seem to get either of it to work.

for 1) I couldn't really find any examples or documentation, so i just tried around by a) defining multiple source-class-tags or by b) using `javax.faces.component.UIInput` as source-class. Neither worked.

for 2) I tried

```
@ListenerFor(systemEventClass = PostValidateEvent.class, sourceClass = UIInput.class)
```

which worked neither for UIInput nor for html.HtmlInputText.

Now, when I duplicate the same XML-configuration for all the other types of HTML-Inputs, this does the trick, but it just clutters up the xml and altogether seems quite annoying to me.

So the question is: Am I generally doing something wrong with the @ListenerFor annotation? Is there a restriction on which source-classes are possible, i.e. why can't I use the more generic UIInput? Is there a more efficient way to register the listener for all those different inputs than repeating the XML? And finally: I'd rather like to implement `ComponentSystemEventListener`. Assuming that the above problem was resolved, I'd just change the `implements`-Statement and implement the abstract `processEvent` accordingly, right? Would that work just the same or is the registration/xml-config different in this case (e.g. maybe `<component-system-event-listener>` instead of just `<system-event-listener>`?

(and as an after-note: is it just me or is it kind of hard to find any non-trivial examples for this kind of stuff on the web?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ListenerFor` is supposed to be set on an `UIComponent` or `Renderer` implementation, not on a standalone `SystemEventListener` implementation. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ListenerFor.html) (emphasis mine):

> **The default implementation must support attaching this annotation to `UIComponent` or `Renderer` classes.** In both cases, the annotation processing described herein must commence during the implementation of any variant of `Application.createComponent()` and must complete before the `UIComponent` instance is returned from `createComponent()`. The annotation processing must proceed according to an algorithm semantically equivalent to the following.
>
> ...

In order to have a global listener, not specific to an `UIComponent` or `Renderer`, your best bet is creating and registering a `PhaseListener` which subscribes the listener to the view root.

```
public class PostValidateListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        event.getFacesContext().getViewRoot()
            .subscribeToViewEvent(PostValidateEvent.class, new InputPostValidationListener()); // Capitalize class name?
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in faces-config.xml:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.PostValidateListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

You can even make your `InputPostValidationListener` itself a `PhaseListener`.

```
public class InputPostValidationListener implements PhaseListener, SystemEventListener {

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        event.getFacesContext().getViewRoot().subscribeToViewEvent(PostValidateEvent.class, this);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I actually read that line, but somehow I got it totally wrong. I kind of had "attach _the (so annotated) listener_ to a UIComponent", not "attach _the annotation_ to an implementation of UIComponent". My bad.

Comment: A consolitation is that I myself have ever made exactly the same mistake after JSF2 was out. Such an annotation would make completely sense on a `SystemEventListener` implementation, but no. I had to read the javadoc more than twice and dive in the source of the JSF implementation to figure what the heck that annotation is for. I think the annotation name is just a bit poorly chosen.

Comment: That is indeed comforting. With all those questions posted over the past months (plus the ones I got my head round without having to ask) I sometimes feel really stupid about JSF... I take comfort in telling myself that at least the later problems/questions deal with less obvious things, meaning: I get deeper into the topic... One can hope!