# Styling UIInputs that fail validation

Tags: validation, jsf, styling

## the problem

I'm trying to work with form validation in jsf 1.2. I have a form with rows of two input text fields.

I enter two rows of data, with one bad cell, like this:

```
| :) | :/ |
| :) | :) |
```

The validator is called once for each row, but checks both fields.
Each `UIInput` that fails validation is added to a list of failed `UIComponent`s.
The method for the submit action finally gets to run.
First it restores any saved styles.
Then it loops over the failed `UIComponent`s.
Inside the loop, it saves the current style, then sets the style to "badInput".

But when the page loads, both end-cells have the "badInput" style:

```
| :) | :/ |
| :) | :/ |
```

## my code

This is my validator, a method on the managed bean that handles this page:

```
public void validateTime(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
{
  UIInput out = (UIInput) component.findComponent("out");

  for (UIComponent uic : Arrays.asList(component, out))
  {
    String time = (String) ((UIInput)uic).getSubmittedValue();

    if (!StringToTime.isValid(time))
    {
      // mark that we found invalid times
      validTimes = false;

      // save the failed component
      // the click method will change the style during the render phase
      failedUics.add(uic);  // List<UIComponent>
      badComps.put(uic.getClientId(context), uic);  // Map<String, UIComponent>
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the table of input fields:

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{entryHandler.tableAttends}" value="#{entryHandler.attends}" var="range">
  <h:column>
    <div>
      <h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText value="In: " />
        <h:inputText value="#{range.start}" id="in" validator="#{entryHandler.validateTime}" />
      </h:outputLabel>

      <h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText value="Out: " />
        <h:inputText value="#{range.end}" id="out" />
      </h:outputLabel>

      <h:commandLink action="#{entryHandler.delAttend}" value="X" styleClass="removeTime" />
    </div>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I've tried applying the bad input style these two ways:

```
for (UIComponent target : failedUics)
{
  log.debug("target client id: " + target.getClientId(context));

  Map<String, Object> attr = target.getAttributes();

  // save the style before changing it
  String style = (String) attr.get("styleClass");
  originalStyle.put(target.getClientId(context), style);

  // add the badInput css class
  if (style == null) style = "";
  attr.put("styleClass", "badInput " + style);
}
failedUics = new ArrayList<UIComponent>();
```

and the second:

```
UIComponent root = context.getViewRoot();
for (String clientId : badComps.keySet())
{
  root.invokeOnComponent(context, clientId, new BadInputCallback(originalStyle));
}
badComps = new HashMap<String, UIComponent>();
```

where this is the callback function:

```
private static class BadInputCallback implements ContextCallback
{
  private final Map<String, String> originalStyle;

  public BadInputCallback(Map<String, String> originalStyle)
  {
    this.originalStyle = originalStyle;
  }

  @Override
  public void invokeContextCallback(FacesContext context, UIComponent target)
  {
    Map<String, Object> attr = uic.getAttributes();

    // save the style before changing it
    String style = (String) attr.get("styleClass");
    originalStyle.put(target.getClientId(context), style);

    // add the badInput css class
    if (style == null) style = "";
    attr.put("styleClass", "badInput " + style);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because there is physically **only one** input component in the component tree, whose state changes whenever the parent `UIData` component iterates over every item of the model. When you want to set the `styleClass` dynamically, you basically need to let it depend on the currently iterated item, like so:

```
<h:dataTable ... var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText ... styleClass="#{item.bad ? 'badInput' : ''}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Or when you're already on JSF 2.x, then check `UIInput#isValid()` instead whereby the `UIInput` is referenced via implicit EL variable `#{component}`, like so:

```
<h:dataTable ... var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText ... styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'badInput'}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This problem is already identified before and taken into account in among others the JSF 1.2 targeted [`SetFocusListener` phase listener on The BalusC Code](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html) and the JSF 2.0 [`<o:highlight>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) of JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org).

Both have under the covers the same approach: they collect the client IDs of all invalidated input components and pass them as an array to JavaScript code which in turn sets the desired class name via HTML DOM.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is #{component} in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035760/what-exactly-is-component-in-el/)
- [how to set ui-state-error class to h:selectOneMenu on validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167542/how-to-set-ui-state-error-class-to-hselectonemenu-on-validation-error/)
- [Styling input component after validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781928/styling-input-component-after-validation-failed/)
- [Eclipse errors on #{component.valid}: "valid cannot be resolved as a member of component”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941072/eclipse-errors-on-component-valid-valid-cannot-be-resolved-as-a-member-of-c/)

Comment: Thanks for solving both my practical problem and my wrong-thinking. I was definitely expecting the `UIData` loop to create many `UIComponents`. For anyone else passing by, [this answer about taghandlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/659715) also helped my thinking.